# erlang OTP app using rebar, dev environment

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I am in the process or learning erlang OTP and rebar and I have put together a small example app using a couple of dependencies: cowboy and lager.

I have issued

```
rebar get-deps
rebar compile
```

And things went smoothly. Now I want to fire up my console to test things around but it is not obvious to me how to start the dependency applications.

I tried issuing a

```
rebar generate
```

In order to get all the orchestration of firing up the apps, even though it's overkill for just development tests, but I miserably failed getting the following dump

```
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
eheap_alloc: Cannot allocate 1459620480 bytes of memory (of type "old_heap").
Aborted
```

The ebin dir only has beam files for the app I wrote but not the dependencies, I see the dependencies have their own ebin directory inside the main app deps directory, how would I go about having them available in a console to start them up?

I would appreciate if someone can shed some light as to what the common practice is for the dev env with multiple OTP apps.

I have read a couple of tutorials but they are mostly targeted at the rebar release cycle and not the development process.

TIA

Comment: I found the cause of the **chrash dump** generated by `rebar generate`, I was using the rebar downloadable script and not building rebar myself and including it on my PATH, so after I properly built rebar for my platform it no longer takes a lifetime to put together the release and I can sucessfully start all apps. So my question diverts to: Is using `rebar generate` the common way to fire up your console and test your development progress??

Comment: I don't know if it's common, but I do that in order to test the application the same way that it will be running when deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the modules you pull into the deps directory should typically be called from within your application code - and your application can be typically invoked from the Erlang shell using the **application:start/1** function. If you haven't yet, I strongly suggest that you read Chapter 12, "OTP Behaviors", of Francesco Cesarini's excellent book **Erlang Programming** - it's a great practical introduction for what you're attempting.

Comment: https://github.com/basho/rebar/wiki/Release-handling - describes the use of the rebar-created script that does what you want: rel/app-name/bin/app-name start/stop

Comment: Indeed, the rebar script seems to work just fine. It's just that initially I thought that the release process was way too heavy, since on my misconfigured environment it was taking too long and crashing in the middle. So it seems that this is the common practice. In regards your first answer, remember its OTP compliant applications we're talking about right? I would expect to be able to start it on a compliant way?

Comment: I am under the impression that the rebar-generated application start/stop script is indeed OTP compliant, so perhaps I'm misunderstanding something important :)

Comment: Hey snwight, I had not given you the accept on this one becasue I was failing to start all involved applications on the shell and at the same time having issues with rebar generate. But your answer is correct, I was just failing to load all involved applications including deps because I didn't know how to use the -pa option when starting the shell. Well you know the noob factor can go great lenghts. Thank you for your time.